# How to pass a list of parameters contained in an array to bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) I want to prepare, execute, and get results from *an SQL statement with an `IN` function*, such as this:

```
SELECT id FROM records WHERE isbn IN ( 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' );
```

The parameters intended for `IN` are actually dynamic, so they will be in an array, differing in length with each run.

For one run, imagine the array is:

```
$list = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

So the prepared statement would have to look like this, with three question marks:

```
SELECT id FROM records WHERE isbn IN ( ?, ?, ? );
```

Here's what I have:

```
$question_marks = str_repeat('?, ', count($list));
$question_marks = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $question_marks);

$stmt = $linkID->prepare("SELECT id FROM records WHERE isbn IN ($question_marks)");

$types = str_repeat('s', count($list));

$stmt->bind_param($types, $list); // this is not working (error below)
```

The error I get is:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

How to pass *a list of parameters contained in an array* to [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)?

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$list);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PHP 5.6, you can do this easily with the help of the [unpacking Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (`...$var`) and use [get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) instead of [bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

```
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$list);
$stmt->get_result();
```